# Is there a way to mix @variables with placeholders in Perl using DBI and MySQL/MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, myisam

I have a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
    foo.bar
FROM
    foo
WHERE
    foo.bang = 0
    AND (
        CASE
            WHEN ? = 2 THEN foo.baz IS NOT NULL
            WHEN ? = 1 THEN foo.baz IS NULL
            ELSE ? NOT IN (1, 2)
        END
    )
    AND (
        (? = 0)
        OR
        (foo.bang = ?)
    )
```

where the placeholders (`?`) are used as inputs for filter parameters:

```perl
my $query = $aboveQuery;
my ( $results ) = $dbh->DBI::db::selectall_arrayref(
    $query,
    { Slice => {} },
    $bazFilter,
    $bazFilter,
    $bazFilter,
    $bangFilter,
    $bangFilter,
);
```

This works, but it's not very reader-friendly.
MySQL supports `@` variables, which would increase readability:

```sql
SET @bazFilter = ?;  -- passed in via selectall_arrayref or execute;
SET @bangFilter = ?;

SELECT
    foo.bar
FROM
    foo
WHERE
    foo.bang = 0
    AND (
        CASE
            WHEN @bazFilter = 2 THEN foo.baz IS NOT NULL
            WHEN @bazFilter = 1 THEN foo.baz IS NULL
            ELSE @bazFilter NOT IN (1, 2)
        END
    )
    AND (
        (@bangFilter = 0)
        OR
        (foo.bang = @bangFilter)
    );
```

I'd like to do something like this instead:

```perl
my $query = $aboveAtVariablizedQuery;
my ( $results ) = $dbh->DBI::db::selectall_arrayref(
    $query,
    { Slice => {} },
    $bazFilter,
    $bangFilter,
);
```

but MyISAM apparently won't do multiple statements in a single query.

My google-fu is failing me.
Is there a good way to mix-and-match the @variables with the placeholders?

Comment: `$dbh->do('SET @bazFilter = ?;', ...); $dbh->do('SET @bangFilter = ?;', ...); $dbh->selectall_arrayref(...)`?

Comment: Tip: `$dbh->DBI::db::selectall_arrayref` should simply be `$dbh->selectall_arrayref`

Comment: @ikegami I'd rather do it all in one go, rather than three separate calls to `$dbi` (and my shop's code requirements force us to fully-qualify packages when we use them, hence the `DBI::db::` in the above code).

Comment: You want to execute three queries, so you have to execute three queries. There's no way around that.

Comment: Re "*and my shop's code requirements force us to fully-qualify packages*", That's bad. You are requiring the caller to have internal knowledge of the workings of DBI and impose dependencies on those internals. Your approach is very fragile, and very prone to error, and prone to breaking. Bad, bad, bad. This is the very opposite of that for which a programmer should strive

Comment: For sub calls, it makes sense (though I prefer the simper approach of only importing implicitly using `use Foo qw( ); use Bar qw( symbol );`), but not for method calls

Comment: @ikegami I'm not starting an argument with you about my shop's code requirements. Overall I agree with you and I've argued against it but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do each statement separately, using `execute` not one of the fetch methods.

@ variables are local to the connection, so there is no problem with contamination between threads.

If the goal is to have a single query with no repeated substitutions, then consider:

```
SELECT  foo.bar
    FROM  ( SELECT baz = ?, bang = ? ) AS init
    JOIN  foo
    WHERE   foo.bang = 0
        AND (
            CASE
                WHEN init.baz = 2 THEN foo.baz IS NOT NULL
                WHEN init.baz = 1 THEN foo.baz IS NULL
                ELSE init.baz NOT IN (1, 2)
            END
        )
        AND (
            (init.bang = 0)
            OR
            (foo.bang = init.bang)
        );
```

Comment: While I was hoping to actually mix `@` variables in with the `?` placeholders, this **definitely** meets my (implied) goal of a single _readable_ query with no repeated substitutions. Thanks!